# EXM not dispatching emails, timeout error, sql exception

Tags: exm

We are using: 
Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 170407)

Email Experience Manager 4.0.1 rev. 170105

Exception details as follows:

```
10000 17:25:39 ERROR Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Message: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to     
completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated.
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.RunParser(BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsyncContinuedOnSuccess(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsyncContinued(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.CopyBatchesAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, String updateBulkCommandText, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestContinuedAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestAsync(CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalAsync(CancellationToken ctoken)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServerAsync(Int32 columnCount, CancellationToken ctoken)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(IDataReader reader)
at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Data.SqlDbEcmDataProvider.AddToDispatchQueue(Guid messageId, MessageType messageType, IEnumerable`1 recipients, Dictionary`2 customPersonTokens)
at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Gateways.DefaultEcmDataGateway.AddToDispatchQueue(Guid messageId, MessageType messageType, IEnumerable`1 recipients, Dictionary`2 customPersonTokens)
at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Dispatch.DispatchManager.AddRecipients(DispatchNewsletterArgs args, QueueOrganizer queueOrganizer, HashSet`1 optOutContactListIds)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
Message: The wait operation timed out


ManagedPoolThread #2 17:25:39 INFO  Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated.
ManagedPoolThread #2 17:25:39 INFO  
ManagedPoolThread #2 17:25:39 INFO  Dispatch Message (Test exm): Finished
Result:          ABORTED
Message Id:      {EA3FDFEE-C109-4C4A-ADB8-36ECD98FC51A}
Message Path:    /sitecore/content/Email Campaign/Messages/2017/07/10T140501/Test exm
Recipients Processed:    
Message Total Sent Recipients:    0
Message Total Failed Recipients:  0
Included Recipient Lists: Test List
Excluded Recipient Lists: Common Global Opt-out
```

Comment: have you made sure the exm there's no issues with the connection to the db? and have you ran script Sitecore.EmailExperienceManager.sql against reporting db?https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/30/setting_up_exm/configuration/configure_the_exm_for_the_first_time

Comment: What's the rough number of recipients? It looks like that method attempts to do a bulk write of the recipients into the dispatch queue. It may be that if you have a large list of recipients, it's timing out writing that data to the database.

Comment: @olusegun-orija You're aware that Sitecore 8.2.3 is not supported by EXM 3.4.1?

That being said, this looks like a configuration error. Make sure the exm.master connection string is correct and verify that you can get a connection. If it is, as suggested by Matthew, try changing the setting DispatchEnqueueBatchSize in App_Config\Include\EmailExperience\Sitecore.EmailExperience.ContentManagement.config to a lower value.

Comment: @josedbaez That script does not exist and is not required for EXM 3.3+

Comment: @JacobNielsen good catch, forgot to mention the setting to tune that.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the answers so far...
The connection strings are all fine, checked them, checked my connection, that all seems fine.
Now I have another issue with the exm module not loading correctly.
When you try to create a message, once you've select your template and given the message a name, it goes into the message option screen, but it just keeps loading and nothing reasonable in the logs this time(nothings regarding errors).
I've done a re-install of exm on the environment but still the same problem.